# Решите пожалуйста задачу по массивам

Tags: java

Введите с клавиатуры целое число X.
Выведите на экран номер элемента массива, который равен X.
Если таких элементов несколько, выведите меньший номер.
Выводить на экран номер элемента, который считается от 1.
То есть, начальный элемент массива при выводе на экран считать первым.
Если такого элемента нет, выведите "NO".

Пример:

Входные данные
5
1 2 3 4 5
6

Выходные данные
NO
,
,

Входные данные
6
5 7 -12 4 86 7
7

Выходные данные
2

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();   
}
```

----Теперь сижу в ступоре

Comment: Не, никто не решит. Сам попробуй и если что-то не будет получаться, - подскажем. Иначе не стать тебе программистом

Comment: Не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы вводимые числа записывались в массив. Написал код до такого состояния:  int n=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n];
        for (int i;;) {
            i=sc.nextInt();
            if (i=n)
                System.out.println(); ----Теперь сижу в ступоре

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = sc.nextInt()`

Comment: Поместите то, что сделали в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

в задании ничего не сказано про массив, а значит делаем как нормальный программист по минимуму задайте массив вручную в самом начале`int []arr=new arr[]{3,5,6,7,2)`
а когда будете выводить номер элемента выводите номер массива +1`System.out.print(arr[0+1]`
примерно так

Answer (score 0):

После того, как ты считал массив с помощью цикла, ты можешь точно так же проверить есть ли в нем искомое число. Разумеется это число сначала нужно считать

```
int X = sc.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (a[i] == X) {
        //Вывести на консоль номер совпавшего элемента и можно завершать программу 
    }
}
```

Следует помнить что индексация массива начинается с нуля, а нумерация всегда с единицы, то есть номером элемента будет его индекс увеличенный на единицу.

По той причине, что в это цикле for мы завершаем программу, если находим необходимый искомый элемент массива, весь код ниже этого цикла будет выполняться только в том случае, если мы его не нашли, поэтому туда можно добавить вывод на консоль "NO"

```
System.out.println("NO");
```